# Where does Xcode 3 put archived applications

Tags: iphone, xcode

What base path does Xcode 3 put archived (iPhone) applications under?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you right-click on an archived application, you can select *"Show in Finder"* to get to their location.  As of Xcode 3.2.5, the location is `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications`.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. I don't have an Xcode 3 install in front of me, so "Show in Finder" wasn't an option.

Comment: Was this different in earlier versions? Or is it a hidden folder? I'm trying to find it in Time Machine backups, and am only seeing `Remote Computers` and `Screenshots`.

Comment: Yes in previous versions it was in `~/Library/Mobile Device/Archived Applications`.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, that's actually what I needed.

Comment: and "some day" they will be in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives`. Isn't it a funny game?

Answer (score 1):

For those people coming here looking for it (like I did) Xcode 4 puts the archived apps in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives